# При наведении на картинку должен появляться крестик ее удаления

Tags: html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте!

Как при наведении на картинку сделать так, чтобы в правом верхнем углу появлялся "крестик"(закрыть) и фон картинки плавно затемнялся.

Чтобы получилось примерно, как на картинке ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('.content.clossable').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.close').animate({opacity:1},100)
        },function(){
            $(this).find('.close').animate({opacity:0},100)
        }
)
```

```css
.close {
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
    right:0px;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background-color:#efefef;
    z-index: 5;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 150ms;
    background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAQAAAC1+jfqAAAAiElEQVR42r2RsQrDMAxEBRdl8SDcX8lQPGg1GBI6lvz/h7QyRRXV0qUULwfvwZ1tenw5PxToRPWMC52eA9+WDnlh3HFQ/xBQl86NFYJqeGflkiogrOvVlIFhqURFVho3x1moGAa3deMs+LS30CAhBN5nNxeT5hbJ1zwmji2k+aF6NENIPf/hs54f0sZFUVAMigAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==) no-repeat;
    text-align:right;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;    
}
.close:hover, .close:focus {
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAQAAAC1+jfqAAAAqklEQVR4XqWRMQ6DMAxF/1Fyilyj2SmIBUG5QcTCyJA5Z8jGhlBPgRi4TmoDraVmKFJlWYrlp/g5QfwRlwEVNWVa4WzfH9jK6kCkEkBjwxOhLghheMWMELUAqqwQ4OCbnE4LJnhr5IYdqQt4DJQjhe9u4vBBmnxHHNzRFkDGjHDo0VuTAqy2vAG4NkvXXDHxbGsIGlj3e835VFNtdugma/Jk0eXq0lP//5svi4PtO01oFfYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=");
}

.content {
    width:128px;
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 5px;
    float:left;
}
.content:after {
    content:'\A';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.content:hover:after {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content clossable" >
    <div class="close"></div>
    <img id="Image1" src = "http://blog.grio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

вариант на css

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: 'segoe ui', sans-serif;
}
.b-pict {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: url('http://www.3daudiomagic.com/images/Nature%20Walk%20C_250.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
.b-pict:after,
.b-pict__close {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.b-pict:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.b-pict__close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  z-index: 9;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #222;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.b-pict:hover:after,
.b-pict:hover .b-pict__close {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-pict">
  <a href="#" class="b-pict__close" title="DEL">x</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вроде бы так

```js
$(".sel").click(function() {
  $(".images").hide();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.images {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
.images img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.sel {
  display: none;
  border: 2px solid #fefefe;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.images:hover .sel {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #fefefe;
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <img src="https://im3-tub-kz.yandex.net/i?id=41a7f16f65b89b547956fecb39338ba2&n=33&h=215&w=324" alt="">
  <div class="sel">X</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```